# Home page title disappears

Tags: magento2, title

I have installed Magento 2.2.3. For some reason, the meta title disappears from the home page randomly without anyone touching it. I suspect it changes when updating Magento mode. Please reply with your suggestion.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Meta title in CMS page **Search Engine Optimization** tab